# Virtualbox: How to connect to the display when launched via vagrant?

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I've used vagrant to set up ubuntu 12.10. How can I actually connect to the graphical desktop? There doesn't seem to be a way in the Virtualbox manager. It shows a preview but the 'show' icon is disabled.

It's a bit of a fiddle but I can suspend the vagrant then use the VirtualBox manager to start the VM and it connects to the display. I'd rather I didn't have to do this though because it might mess up NFS shares/IP addresses, etc.

Comment: Also see this question: [enabling gui in Vagrantfile settings](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19013851)

Comment: Seeing as the answer should not be part of the question, you should cut it out and submit it by using the "answer your own question" button.

Comment: With VirtualBox 5.0, this becomes very simple; see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23297652/5419599

Answer (score 1):

```
config.vm.boot_mode = :gui
```

See http://docs-v1.vagrantup.com/v1/docs/config/vm/boot_mode.html

Comment: This results in an error in vagrant 1.7

vm:
* The following settings shouldn't exist: boot_mode

Answer (score 1):

you edit the Vagrantfile and you add this line in section provider:

```
   config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|

     vb.gui = true

   end
```